# Can I send information from browser console (via AJAX) to my php file on local/remote host?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

For example:
Stackoverflow's [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)

I push F12 in Crome web-browser and in console put next:

```
var item = document.querySelectorAll('.question-summary');
var outputValue = item.length;
outputValue;
```

The output I get is `15`

Question is can I send this info (the output value) to my myfile.php file (for example get sing in one of my divs `There are 15 questions on that particular stackoverflow's page` via `<? echo 'There are ' . outputValue . ' questions on that particular stackoverflow's page'; ?>`), so in future I'll be able to put this information to MySQL database (but for now I just need to print out `outputValue` on myfile.php )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a GET request, you could pass the length as a query string parameter -

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "server.php?question-summaries="+item.length);
xmlhttp.send();
```

server.php

```
if (is_numeric($_GET['question-summaries'])) {
    // Insert into database
}
```